# Html5 video как сделать подгрузку?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Добрый день!

Мне нужно сделать остановку html5 video плеера на момент когда текущее время равно концу буфера, дать загрузить 5 секунд видео и продолжить.

Пробую такой вариант:

```
var TEMP_TIME = 0;
function dopLoad() {
    TEMP_TIME = vid.currentTime;
    if ((TEMP_TIME + 5) > vid.buffered.end(0)) {
        $('.poster').removeClass('display-none');
        console.log('Need load!');
        vid.pause();
        vid.currentTime = vid.buffered.end(0);
    } else {
            $('.poster').addClass('display-none');
            console.log('Not need load!');
            vid.currentTime = TEMP_TIME;
    }
}
```

Вызываю dopLoad() каждую секунду.

Подскажите, как правильно это написать?

Comment: Дополните пожалуйста до рабочего варианта — что бы можно было попробовать.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа)

Answer (score 1):

Как то так:

```
var checkLoadId = setInterval(dopLoad, 1000); // интервал проверки
var loadIntervalId;  // Интервал во время догрузки видео

function dopLoad() {
    if ((vid.currentTime + 5) > vid.buffered.end(0)) { //проверяем что осталось менее 5 секунд видео
        $('.poster').removeClass('display-none');
        vid.pause();  // ставим на паузу
        clearInterval(checkLoadId); // Останавливаем интервал проверки
        loadIntervalId = setInterval(dopLoad, 5000); // запускаем интервал догрузки — та же функция но проверка будет раз в 5 секунд
    } else {
        $('.poster').addClass('display-none'); 
        if(vid.paused){ 
            clearInterval(loadIntervalId); // останавливаем интервал догрузки
            vid.play(); // возобнавляем воспроизведение
            checkLoadId = setInterval(dopLoad, 1000); // запускаем интервал проверки
        }
    }
}
```